# How to add data to many excel cells

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am going to retrieve information from db and put into table my table as follow

[image]

here I am merging cells but I cannot add data because it gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    for name, score in (scores):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

scores = (
    ['ankit', 1000, 1264, 4125],
    ['rahul',   100, 1452, 4578],
    ['priya',  300, 123, 1452],
    ['harshita',    50, 412,458],
)

row = 12
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for name, score in (scores):
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, score)
    row += 1
```

I am going to add like that shown with the above code but I cannot, here `ID` cells should be filled with numbers order automatically according to the length of data. please can anyone help me with these issues? it taking a lot of time. please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have to for tuple of lists for your score entries, the way you are reading the entries from it is not correct.

eg:

```
scores = (
    ['ankit', 1000, 1264, 4125],
    ['rahul',   100, 1452, 4578],
    ['priya',  300, 123, 1452],
    ['harshita',    50, 412,458],
)
```

The following gives error:

```
for name, score in scores:
    print(name, score)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-53788305b060> in <module>
----> 1 for name, score in scores:
      2     print(name, score)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Instead you can do it this way:

```
row = 12
col = 0
for entry in scores:
    name = entry[0]
    score = sum(entry[1:])
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, score)
    row += 1
```

I have written the above code to store the sum of scores in one column, if you want individual scores to be split and stored along the same row then this won't be enough. Let me know the library you are using to do this, so I can try to help there to.

Here is the code mate! Hope this helps!

```py
import xlsxwriter as xls

scores = (
    ['ankit', 1000, 1264, 4125],
    ['rahul', 100, 1452, 4578],
    ['priya', 300, 123, 1452],
    ['harshita', 50, 412, 458],
)
# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xls.Workbook('merge_scores.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
center = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center'})

#First write the headers separately merging the cell ranges required for the scores
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Name")
worksheet.merge_range(0, 1, 0, 3, "Scores", cell_format=center)

#Starting at 2nd row whose index will be one to put the actual data in
row = 1
col = 0
for entry in scores:
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, entry)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

[image: merge_scores.xlsx workbook view]

For additional cell formatting you may wanna take a look at these links:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes your answer did not work in my case it just summed the scores I want to place data into individual column. The library is `xlsxwriter` as shown in tags

Comment: from your image are you expecting something like 
| Name | Scores |
|-------|--------------------|
| Ankit | 1000 | 1264 | 4125 |

Trying to put as a markdown table, sorry for my lack of understanding in doing it clear, but does above representation fits your requirement?

Comment: no this data is just an example it is not real data I was just going to show you how I want to place each data into each cell I do not need to sum the data. Please let me know if you do not understand again

Comment: @Nerd I have added the piece of code in my above answer, see if it fits what you are looking for